# how can I get the app version in Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, version

I want to use the version that I have set in app.yaml as a querystring variable for my css and js files, so that my user's browsers will grab the latest version if it has been cached when I update my app.  I cannot find a good reference for the "appengine" package, which I assume has the variable that I am looking for.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following appengine/context method:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#VersionID

Comment: Please avoid link only answers : they tend to become obsolete too fast. Copy the relevant part in here.